# Application.yml aren't detected by spring boot inside docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

For some reason, application.yml file isn't detected inside docker by spring boot.
When running the application locally it works fine and all the variables are detected normally.

Here is my dockerfile - https://github.com/smuryginim/api-rate-limiter/blob/e7599cc10fbd0de8f33bdd48c51a289e28c01e1a/docker/Dockerfile#L42

I run it with docker-compose file. - https://github.com/smuryginim/api-rate-limiter/blob/e7599cc10fbd0de8f33bdd48c51a289e28c01e1a/docker-compose.yml

`docker-compose up -d ratelimiter`

The `application.yml` file is presented in fat jar, which is launched

[image: Content of the fat jar]

But I have the next error

```
sm-ratelimiter | Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
sm-ratelimiter |        at sm.tech.RateLimiterApplication.jedisPoolConfig(RateLimiterApplication.kt:22)
sm-ratelimiter |        at sm.tech.RateLimiterApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6df302e5.CGLIB$jedisPoolConfig$0(<generated>)
sm-ratelimiter |        at sm.tech.RateLimiterApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6df302e5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed5e11ba.invoke(<generated>)
sm-ratelimiter |        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
```

RateLimiterApplication - https://github.com/smuryginim/api-rate-limiter/blob/e7599cc10fbd0de8f33bdd48c51a289e28c01e1a/src/main/kotlin/sm/tech/RateLimiterApplication.kt

Comment: What's the reason that you somehow create manually a shadowJar instead of using the Spring Boot provided tasks/mechanisms? Only by using the latter, you can be sure that the file structure within your JAR is the way Spring Boot expects it to be.

Comment: >  using the Spring Boot provided tasks/mechanisms? Thanks, do you have some link for how to?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives